# Source for "Miktzas HaYom K'Kulo"?

Tags: sources-mekorot, mourning-aveilus, nozir

What is the source for "Miktzas HaYom K'Kulo"? I realize it applies to Availus (mourning) and it is also brought up regarding Nazir but I could not find its source?

Comment: See: Pesachim 4a:2 "And learn from it that with regard to the halakhot of mourning, the legal status of part of the day is like that of an entire day." - https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.4a.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: Nazir megillah and niddah are the 3 masechtot. There are very long Tosfot

Comment: @Shmuel the :2 is a made up Sefaria convention

Comment: @robev did not know that. Thank you! Why did they do that?

Comment: @Shmuel convenience, so you can more easily link to a specific line

Comment: @robev ah okay. That makes sense. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Larry and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!